# Given that $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = 1$, calculate $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{kt}$

Tags: calculus

I've solved this problem, but I'm unsure if my reasoning is correct. Please review my understanding of the problem and whether or not my reasoning is correct. Thank you.

We know that $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = 1$.

We want to know $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{t}$.

$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{t}$ = (k) $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{kt}$. This is because we are multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $k$. Therefore, by the limit laws, we are not changing the limit?

As $t$ goes to $0$, $kt$ goes to $0$:

(k) $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{kt}$ = (k) $\lim\limits_{kt \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{kt}$.

Let $kt = \theta$.

(k) $\lim\limits_{kt \to 0} \frac{\sin(kt)}{kt}$ = (k) $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$ = (1)k = k

Comment: Please use MathJax to write the math: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @Lovsovs I managed to fix it. Not sure how to include the thetas, though. :S

Comment: For greek letters, you write \greekletter.

Comment: @DavidBowman Thanks!

Comment: @ThePointer Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t = k\theta$ then if $\theta \to 0, t \to 0$ and so;

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(k\theta)}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{k}{k}\cdot \frac{\sin(k\theta)}{\theta} = k \cdot \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(k\theta)}{k\theta} = k \cdot \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} =k \cdot 1 = k$$

Comment: There is an error in your calculations?

Comment: Ok, it's fixed. Everything you did was basically correct, I just submitted this as an answer to close the question. You might want to look at your substitution though, that's where you error is.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Which substitution are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Set $kt = x$

Hence your limit becomes

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Hence your limit is then $k$

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Specify exactly where my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: @ThePointer It's not, sorry. You made a mess with not being able to write properly in LaTeX so I got confused.

Comment: My apologies. :(